# How do i get rid of the white border around my lines?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

I am making a 2d animation and these white borders appear around my lineart. (I'm using the 2d version of blender) does it have something to do with my brush?(I used the ink pen brush for this)
(also, this doesn't just appear in the program, if I render the animation the white border is still visible)

*EDIT: I made a new project to see if it still occurred there. I used different brushes and such, but the white borders were still around it. I did find out something new, though.  The borders don't appear between different channels. If have one object and make a new one, then when i draw something on the new object the borders become visible.*

Comment: Possibly something in your brush settings is doing this, haven't used the animation software enough to tell you on the spot though, would need to see your settings.

Comment: Sounds like you miss premultiplied alpha for the alpha channel. I have no idea where to activate it though.

Comment: @Tiles         alpha channel? what/where's that

Comment: Alpha channel can be processed in two ways. Without premultiplied alpha and with premultiplied alpha. The second method should remove the halo pixels. But i have as told no idea where you need to activate it.